# Producing PDFs with non-Latin characters using OpenOffice.org Writer

Tags: open-source, openoffice

I am using OpenOffice.org Writer, I can't export a document with non-Latin languages into a PDF file. All the characters disappear. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had no problem producing the following PDF from OpenOffice Writer 3.1.1 on Windows Vista

[image: example PDF]

Please update your question with a small sample of text that can be pasted into OO writer or a link to a small example ODF document that displays your problem.

```
Arial
Cyrillic capital letter Zhe with breve Ӂ
Arabic letter teh marbuta ة

Batang
Hangul Syllable Sios A Kiyeok삭

Gulim
Random CJK Ideographs 俉俠
```

You should be able to cut the above, paste it into OO Writer, set the fonts as indicated and export to PDF with the same results.